# Performing Binary classification using binary dataset

Tags: data-mining, dataset

Can a dataset with only  binary digits 0's and 1's perform good classification such as decision tree and naive Bayes

Comment: That's just like true and false for the decision trees

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Many data sets are one-hot encoded into only 0s and 1s because some ML algorithms work best that way.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: How can I encode my dataset to work in weka and give correct cross validation

Comment: That is a separate and overly broad question. Since it sounds like you're just starting out, you might want to check out the book that the Weka authors wrote: https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html